SwiftUI Why Button label stay at top of view hierarchy?
A partner told me that my popup is overlayed by another views. I checked by view hierarchy and see some button's labels are staying at top of view hierarchy. I am not sure is it the problem.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Title")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("Button Text")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding()
            .zIndex(1)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay(
            VStack {
                Text("This text should at top")
            }
                .frame(
                    maxWidth: .infinity,
                    maxHeight: .infinity
                )
                .background(Color.red)
                .zIndex(100)
        )
    }
}


Any help!
